# Is it design pattern ? chain

Tags: c#, design-patterns

How call that class\structure ?
Maybe is it design pattern ?

Task:
I have a collection which I need search item.
I have 3 levels for searching.
I create a Matcher chain and search in collection on each levels and pass the collection to next level if doesn't find.

I'm looking for what is design pattern.

```
class Matcher
{
    private readonly Matcher _nextMatcher;
    private readonly Func<lambda, bool> _predicate;

    public Matcher(
        Matcher nextMatcher,
        Func<lambda, bool> predicate)
    {
        _nextMatcher = nextMatcher;
        _predicate = predicate;
    }

    public bool Match(Collection<SomeObject> someObjects,
        IEnumerable<SomeObject> sourceObjects)
    {
        if (!_predicate(someObjects, sourceObjects))
        {
            if (_nextMatcher == null)
                return false;

            return _nextMatcher.Match(someObjects, sourceObjects);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the looks of it, this looks like (a correct) implementation of the [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) design pattern.

Here's another, more .NET-centric example: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx